# Input up is inconsistent and works half of the times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public int hSpeed;
    public int vSpeed;

    private void PlayerInput() {
        var inpRight = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) ? 1 : 0;
        var inpLeft = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) ? 1 : 0;
        var inpUp = Input.GetKeyDown("space") ? 1 : 0;

        Debug.Log(inpUp);

        Unit.velocity.x = (inpRight - inpLeft) * hSpeed;
        Unit.velocity.y = (inpUp) * vSpeed;

        Debug.Log(Unit.velocity.y);
    

        rb.velocity = Unit.velocity * Time.deltaTime;

    }

    private void Update() {
        PlayerInput();
        Debug.Log(rb.velocity);
    
    }

}
```

This is my whole player code and I have no idea why the input up works sometimes, but other times not. The player will sometimes take the input but other times just completly ignore it.

I printed out the inpUp variable and it showed that the inpUp does in fact recive input from the player, but does not move the player upwards.

I thought it was because it was in FixedUpdate() But it seems to not work in Update() Either. Any ideas why?

I did some exploring and found that this works, but I have no idea why it works. IF i for example remove my Custom gravity which is the Unit.velocity.y += grv * Time.fixedDeltaTime; it doesn't work and it won't detect the jump.

New code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public int hSpeed;
    public int vSpeed;
    public float grv;

    private void PlayerInput() {
        var inpRight = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) ? 1 : 0;
        var inpLeft = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) ? 1 : 0;

       Unit.velocity.x = (inpRight - inpLeft) * hSpeed;
       rb.velocity += new Vector2(Unit.velocity.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 
rb.velocity.y);

    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        Unit.velocity.y = grv * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        PlayerInput();   
    }

    private void Update() {
        var inpUp = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W);

        if (inpUp == true) {
            Unit.velocity.y = vSpeed;
        } 
    
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Unit.velocity.y);
    }

}
```

Comment: The documentation says that it is not thread safe on Update. If you want to use it in update. You have to save the values into variables in fixed update.

Comment: @John but when i use it in fixed update the jumpin is detect to slow

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I'll leave other @John to respond to your comment :)

Comment: You know that `GetKeyDown` is only true in one single frame right? Also why not using `GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` which afaik is more efficient since no `string` operations needed? Also what is `Unit`?

Comment: @derHugo I have tried both Keycode.Space and with the string. **Unit** is another scripts where I store variables. GeykeyDown is true one single frame, but the problem is that it dosen't even jump for the frame that it's supposed to jump. I found a fix, but it doesn't make any sence at all

Comment: Usually you should check User Input in `Update` but change Rigidbody values only in `FixedUpdate` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code example:

```
    var inpUp = Input.GetKeyDown("space") ? 1 : 0;
    Unit.velocity.y = (inpUp) * vSpeed;
```

The above code has the effect of setting `Unit.velocity.y` to `1 * vSpeed` on the single frame when the space key is pressed.  However, on the **very next frame**, it sets the `Unit.velocity.y` to `0 * vSpeed` which is 0.  So the velocity is only changed for the tiniest fraction of a second before being set back to 0.

In the second code example you use:

```
    var inpUp = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W);

    if (inpUp == true) {
        Unit.velocity.y = vSpeed;
    }
```

The effect of that code is that the `Unit.velocity.y` value is set when you first press the W key.  It doesn't assign a new value to `Unit.velocity.y` until you press W again.  If you don't press W again, the velocity.y remains equal to `vSpeed` (but is affected by gravity on each FixedUpdate). It is **not reset** on the next frame.

Comment: Dude, You're a god damn legend. Thanks for everything, And I wanna thank everyone else for helping too! :DDDDDDDDDDD